# How to pass jquery values to php without page loading

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass the jquery value "selected" to fetchdata.php without reloading the page.
How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#buttonClass").click(function() {
                    getValueUsingClass();
                });
            });
            function getValueUsingClass() {

                var chkArray = [];

                $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                    chkArray.push($(this).val());
                });

                /* we join the array separated by the comma */
                var selected;
                selected = chkArray.join('#') + "#";

                if (selected.length > 1)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "fetchdata.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
                        type: "GET",
                        data: "val=" + selected, //The data your sending to some-page.php
                        success: function()
                        {
                            console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
                        }
                    });

                    //alert("You have selected " + selected); 
                } else
                {
                    alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="checkboxlist">
            <div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk"> Value 1</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk"> Value 2</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk"> Value 3</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk"> Value 4</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk"> Value 5</div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Get Value Using Class" id="buttonClass"> 
            </div>
</html>
```

fetchdata.php

```
<?php
    foreach($_GET['val'] as $r)
    {
        print_r($r);
    }
?>
```

I am using the GET method to receive the data and the for-each loop to print the array, but I am not getting any values in the PHP file.

Comment: Use `print_r($_GET)` to see what is comming in $_GET request

Comment: @user2376463, just as a heads up, it's a good idea to make sure that your code is formatted properly. It can make it easier to spot errors and minor issues that way! It may be a little overblown, but I'd suggest doing your PHP development work in something like NetBeans, then utilizing its code formatting tool heavily.

Comment: make sure selected has value

Answer (score 2):

change the ajax function like below and make sure about the fectdata.php in the same folder or give the correct path.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fetchdata.php',
    type:'GET',
    data: {val:selected},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 but maybe he sould use chkArray directly instead of selected, shouldnt he?

Comment: stil there is no improvement.. :(

Comment: by the way the following is always true: `(selected.length > 1)`

Comment: Hi steven,ya but i think using array is complex.In php file we can use implode function to obtain data.

Comment: if we select atleast one checkbox it'll true.otherwise false

Comment: yes i know but using # as delimiter is maybe not a good idea. and jquery is able to handle arrays as far as i know.

Comment: to check if you select at least one you shoud do `if(chkArray.length > 0)` instead of the string `selected` which has always at least one character (#) UPDATE: sorry you did > 1 so it should work

Comment: ok.But how to send array values?  iam changing the code :selected = chkArray;    is it right?

Comment: i would do `data: {val:chkArray},` and see what happens in firebug console

Comment: before sending to php just check values correctly showing in javascript itself ''console.log(selected)'' or just send the chkArray as #steven suggest

Comment: In firebug console "AJAX request was successfull ".But the selected values didn't printed

Answer (score 1):

Check if the path to your script is correct:

```
url: 'fetchdata.php',
```

Is this script in your doc root?

Comment: yes, check it in firebug console to see if the file is called properly

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, I'm getting the ajax response here.

Comment: @Linkmichiel please tell me more with examples

Comment: Use the path relative to the root directory. E.g.: if the scripts are located in the directory 'buttons', then you must also direct fetchdata.php to that directory, url: 'buttons/fetchdata.php'

Comment: You can also use a absolute path, url: 'http:// domain.com/buttons/fetchdata.php'

Answer (score 0):

change the following in your code,
in fetchdata.php

```
<?php 
$valArray = explode('@',$_GET['val']); 
foreach($valArray as $val){
echo $val."<br/>";
}
?>
```

In html File,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#buttonClass").click(function() {
getValueUsingClass();
});

});

function getValueUsingClass(){ 
var chkArray = [];

$(".chk:checked").each(function() {
chkArray.push($(this).val());
}); 
/* we join the array separated by the comma */
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join('@') + "@";
if(selected.length > 1)
{ 
$.ajax({
url: "fetchdata.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
type: "GET",
data: "val=" +selected.toString(), //The data your sending to some-page.php
success: function(data1) {  
$("#resultDiv").html(data1);
console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
},
error:function()
{
console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
}   
});

//alert("You have selected " + selected); 
}else
{
alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");   
}
}
```

include the div after a button like

```
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @srividhya there is no change..:( But the firebug console says "Ajax request was successfull"

Comment: add one div tag after a button. the data will be printed in the div